# Soft reset git bare branches

Tags: git, github, fetch, git-bare

I have a set of GIT repositories that I always have different activities on differrent branches and they are all pushed to github

the activities are linked to Redmine and would trigger Redmine to pick up the commits once a push happens. Since the Redmine is not setup to be on the cloud and therefore I can't use the fancy automated github hook to pick up the commits, I have setup the Redmine hook to do a fetch and soft reset to is bare repository when every time a ticket is update.

The problem i have then is the processing time because this is what I do each time:

```
# to update master branch
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
git fetch origin master
git reset --soft FETCH_HEAD
# to update the other branch
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/bug_branch_n
git fetch origin bug_branch_n
git reset --soft FETCH_HEAD
```

With this, I am doing what I want, but the fetch is really taking a bit of time to perform. How can I acutally fetch only once for this exercise and soft reset to the branch that needs updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for [koppen on Github](https://github.com/koppen) who share the code for Redmine Github hook. The solution is to do this: `git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` one command to fetch and update all the branches!